# Add Search Box Glow Effect When Active

Tags: css

I am trying to place a border box shadow around the search field only when the user clicks on it to type. so i need to make a glow effect color like orange when the field is active. how do i do add that? i'm sure it's a pretty simple task though. Below is the CSS. what should i include? please help me. thx (-:

```
.wsite-search {
vertical-align: middle;
width: 170px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 1px black;
border-radius:7px;
}

.wsite-search-input {
float: right;
height: 20px;
padding: 5px 5px !important;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 140px;
border: 0;
color: #ffc500;
float: right;
font-style: italic;
background: url(input-bg.png) no-repeat;
}

.wsite-search-button {
position: relative;
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
float: left;
border: 0;
background: url(submit-bg.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below using `jQuery focus and blur`,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type = 'search']").on("focus",function(){
    $(this).css({
      'boxShadow' : '1px 1px 35px 0px #f75C30',
    }); 
    $("input[type = 'submit']").css({
      'boxShadow' : '1px 1px 35px 0px #f75C30',
    }); 
  });
  
  $("input[type = 'search']").on("blur",function(){
    $(this).css({
      'boxShadow' : '0px 0px 0px 0px #f75C30',
    }); 
    $("input[type = 'submit']").css({
      'boxShadow' : '0px 0px 0px 0px #f75C30',
    }); 
  });
  
});
```

```css
input{
  transition:1s ease;
  border:none;
  background:#111;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search">
<input type="submit">
```

Add this in your

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
```

i.e. jquery cdn.

Then add this just before closing of `</body>`

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input[type='text']").on('focus',function(){
     $('form').css({
     'boxShadow' : '1px 1px 35px 0px #f75C30'
     });
   });
    $("input[type='text']").on('blur',function(){
     $('form').css({
     'boxShadow' : '0px 0px 0px 0px #f75C30'
     });
   });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
form{
  transition:1s ease;
}
```

Comment: Welcome @k4r1 :-) , do accept or up-vote the answer that worked for you.

Comment: @k4r1 you want glow on both submit button and search box. If so, then try updated codes.

Comment: yes of course i want it on the entire search box. check my website to see how this is currently being. www.inpha.co

Comment: this is what i've added so far to my original post in the CSS: .wsite-search-input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #ffc500;
    border-radius:7px;
    transition:2s ease;
}

Comment: and that is what i have in the JS: <script>
 (function($) {
  $(function() {

   $('#wsite-header-search-form  .wsite-search-input').attr('placeholder','Search Store ...')

  });
 }(jQuery));
</script>

Comment: plz provide me with the full codes bz i don't know where to insert the codes that you have provided me with. Thx

Comment: @k4r1 above what I have added will solve your issue, but I suggest you to post your both html and css and surely others developers will help you, I'm adding where to add your codes you can try that.

Comment: I don't know where to place the javascript on my weebly site. i can give you full access to my weebly account so you can modify what needs to be done. can you plz give me your email address @frnt. Probably this will be much easier if you do it straight from the editor.

Comment: weebly does not provide us with HTML for everything. so the search box does not have HTML

Comment: @k4r1 sorry I'm in bit hurry, that's I'm saying you that and if you try to understand above codes then surely that will help :-(

Comment: guess what? i solved my problem after relentless hours of trying and adding different things.

Comment: Wow @k4r1 that's great, keep coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
input{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    color: #555;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 12px;
   width: 250px;
}

input:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    outline: 0 none;
}
```